# Javascript Array.reduce() breaking the page with Error Code 6

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce, array.prototype.map

The webpage works fine as long as I don't pass an initial value, but in that case it just gives me the TypeError because when there's only the last element (as expected). Which is why I am trying to pass 0 as the initial value to the reduce function (line 4 of below snippet). But as soon as I do that, it just breaks the entire page with an error code 6.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**
I'm adding the sum of all the elements of the array, then pushing that sum to another array, removing the first element and repeating the process. When there are no elements left, I want to return 0 from the reduce() function which is why I'm trying to pass an initial value (0).

```
function partsSums(ls) {
  let sumArr = [];
  while (ls.length >= 0) {
    sumArr.push(ls.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur, 0));
    ls.shift();
  }
  return sumArr;
}

partsSums([0, 1, 3, 6, 10]);
```

The output I'm looking for is: `[20, 20, 19, 16, 10, 0]`

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: Change `ls.length >= 0` to `ls.length > 0`. The condition for the while loop will never evaluate to false, since an array's length will never fall below 0, so you have an infinite loop.

Comment: what's the output you are looking for?

Comment: I want to push a 0 into my sumArr when there are no elements left in the ls array on which I'm calling the reduce() fn. if I set the ls.length to >0, then it just stops after the last element. I can push the 0 after the reduce() fn, but is there any way I can do it within the reduce function?

Comment: The output I'm looking for is: [20, 20, 19, 16, 10, 0]

Comment: @Link You could just add `sumArr.push(0)` after the while-loop.

Comment: @3limin4t0r yes, but I was just looking to see if there was any way I could do that without explicitly adding that element (0) to my array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do that:

```js
function partsSums(ls)
  {
  let sumArr = []
    , lng    = ls.length
    ;
  while ( lng >= 0)
    {
    sumArr.push(ls.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur, 0))
    ls.shift()
    --lng
    }
  return sumArr
  }

console.log(JSON.stringify( partsSums([0, 1, 3, 6, 10])  ))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. I should've reduced the length too. My bad. Thanks a ton @Mister Jojo

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is the condition `ls.length >= 0`. This condition leads you to an infinite loop. Change it to `ls.length > 0`

#### Suggestion

It seems you are seeking a cumulative summation from right to left. But your function is not cost-effective. You can use `suffix-sum` for this problem.

```js
const suffixSum = arr => {
  const res = [];
  const {length} = arr;
  res[length] = 0;

  for (let i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    res[i] = res[i+1] + arr[i];
  }
  
  return res;
}

console.log(suffixSum([0, 1, 3, 6, 10]));
```

This algorithm takes `O(n)` time while your algorithm takes `O(n^2)` time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was just trying to learn how I can use the Array.prototype.reduce() fn. Do you mean to say that my webpage breaks because my function is not cost effective?

Comment: Nope! your problem's solution lies in the comments section. It's just because of `ls.length >= 0`. It forces you into an infinite loop.

Comment: I just share a good solution for the 2nd part of your question **What I'm trying to achieve**.

Comment: Thanks, but this still doesn't solve my problem, because I want to add 0 at the end of the result array before returning it, and was trying to do that within Array.prototype.reduce() function.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you're getting an infinite loop because the length of the array will never go below `0`.

As shown in other answers, you can solve that by changing the condition to `ls.length > 0`, but then you won't get the end case of pushing `0` into the result in the final iteration when the array is empty.

Instead of testing the length in the `while()` condition, test it after you call `reduce()` and then break out of the loop.

```js
function partsSums(ls) {
  let sumArr = [];
  while (true) {
    sumArr.push(ls.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur, 0));
    if (ls.length == 0) {
      break;
    }
    ls.shift();
  }
  return sumArr;
}

console.log(partsSums([0, 1, 3, 6, 10]));
```